# Even-length cycle laid out as a star

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, tikz-path

For demonstration purposes, I want to obtain a graph of C10 shaped as a star. I have been working on this for much longer than I should have. I currently have this:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={circle, draw}]
        \foreach \i in {1,...,10}
        {
            \pgfmathisodd{\i};
            \node (N\i) at (360/10*\i:\pgfmathresult?18mm:9mm) {\i};
        }
        \foreach \i in {1,...,10}
        {
            \pgfmathmod{\i}{10}
            \pgfmathadd{\pgfmathresult}{1};
            \path (N\i) edge (N\pgfmathresult);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Which outputs the following abomination:

[image]

I don't know if the same ugliness would happen had I typed out the nodes myself.

Comment: The "abomination" is simply all numbers aligned the same way. Try instead of defining the points recursively like you did and then in a second step add the lines and then the numbers. This should make it better :)

Comment: What I mean is: if you just look at how the numbers are positioned, they look fine. It's just the lines starting from weird places.

Comment: I have given up and written every node one by one. **It works!** The question is even more curious to me now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the manipulations, the result won't be an integer any more. Rather, you'll get numbers like `1.0`, where `.0` is interpreted as an anchor. Therefore I suggest

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={circle, draw}]
        \foreach \i in {1,...,10}
        {
            \pgfmathisodd{\i};
            \node (N\i) at (360/10*\i:\pgfmathresult?18mm:9mm) {\i};
        }
        \foreach \i in {1,...,10}
        {
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\j}{mod(\i,10)+1}
            \path (N\i) edge (N\j);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am aware of the fact that one can shorten the code. This answer is to explain what happens and to provide a way that works which is very close to the code of the question.

Comment: Probably a good idea to fix the circle size so the 10 node isn't bigger than the others.

Comment: Great answer, thank you for being to the point. And to @SandyG, I already have fixed the size inconsistency via putting all nodes in boxes with zero width, and giving any size I like to the nodes.

Answer (score 1):

PGF's `foreach` has quite powerfull tools that you can use here:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={circle, draw}]
    \foreach[evaluate=\i as \j using isodd(\i)] \i in {1,...,10}
    {
        \node (N\i) at (360/10*\i:\j?18mm:9mm) {\i};
    }
    \foreach[remember=\i as \j (initially 10)] \i in {1,...,10}
    {
        \draw (N\i) -- (N\j);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The optional `[evaluate=\i as \j using isodd(\i)]` in the first loop computes `isodd(\i)` and stores the result in macro `\j`.

The optional `[remember=\i as \j (initially 10)]` in the second loop stores `\i`'s content in macro `\j` at the end of the iteration, allowing for this content to be available for the next iteration.

Comment: Thank you for your extended recommendations, but I think marmot's answer is more relevant to the issue/question, since it also explains the cause of the erroneous outcome in the question.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin I agree, this answer is also aimed at those who will find your question later and offer them a simple and robust solution.